# QT - dragLeaveEvent() not always called

Tags: qt, events

The `dragLeaveEvent` is not always called on move mouse out a `QTableWidget`. The bug appears sometimes when I move the mouse quickly outside the `QTableWidget`. I think the bug appears in other `QWidget` based class too.

Has anyone had similar experiences or have a solution ?

Example Code:
http://pastebin.com/Rijyn2cG

My intension behind this is : I would like to delete rows , which I pull out from a table.

Related: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51664

Comment: This is not a good question and even worse bug report. Give some code example which is able to reproduce problem (git-hub link would be best). Now I can suspect (based on long experience with such reports) that your code is faulty and you are trying to move responsibility of your bug to someone else.

Comment: Related issue QTBUG-16555 points to  "Drop Site" demo demo application. Is it reproducible on that application?

Comment: I´ve added the source code. The bug was always in a previous version from Qt, so i think in the current Version it is not fixed.

Comment: QTBUG-16555 is from 2010 and is still "Opened" (not resolved). So I wouldn't expect that new report will change anything. The only choice I can see is to investigate this inside Qt code and provide a fix to Qt or come up with some workaround. Maybe I will take a look on that.